# Notifications email is being sent to Queue members instead of Case owner(user)

Tags: case, notification, email2case

When Case is created the "Status" of the Case will be "New" and "Case Owner" is Queue, Now when we change "Case Owner" from Queue to User, Salesforce is sending notification email to queue members instead of Case Owner(User).

I went into Queue settings and saw "Send email to members" is unchecked

[image]

Can anyone let me know why it is sending emails to Queue members instead of case owner

Comment: Any other workflow rules, flows etc? Might also be worth checking the support settings as their are default rules in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queue email field is left blank which is why it is sending email to all members.
This might help. [Stop email notifications to Queue](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323036&type=1)